# SQL Server CE replace subselect

Tags: sql-server-ce, subquery

I have this SQL statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM history
WHERE (fk_person = 2119) AND (action = 2) AND (date =
                                                      (SELECT MAX(day) AS maxDay
                                                       FROM history AS hist
                                                       WHERE (fk_person = 2119)))
```

As far as I know SQL Server CE does not support subqueries.

How can I replace it?

Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT h1.*
FROM history h1
inner join FROM history h2 on h1.fk_person = h2.fk_person
WHERE h1.fk_person = 2119
AND h1.action = 2
AND h1.day = MAX(h2.day)
```

Comment: it worked after correcting the last line h1.day = Max(h2.day), thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how many records have the same `MAX(day)`, but if you only need one the following might work for you:

```
SELECT TOP (1) *
FROM history
WHERE (fk_person = 2119)
AND (action = 2) 
ORDER BY day DESC
```